# i want to extract date time and IP address from text line

Tags: powershell

My Text line is like this :

```
'891880 2022-09-28 16:48:11 10.10.50.204 "user100-useradmin" 10.10.50.1 8080'
```

I want to get out put in csv file with following columns like this

```
DateTime, SourceIP, UserID
2022-09-28 16:48:11,10.10.50.204,user100-useradmin
```

While From this PowerShell script, i am only getting IP addresses

```
$input_path = "C:\my.txt"
$output_file = "C:\my1.txt"
$regex = ‘\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b’
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

Comment: Take a look at `SubString()`.

Comment: -sikorskys60 thank you for replying actually i am new in powershell coding and dont know much about this 'substring()' if you can share any example it will be very helpful for me thanks again

Comment: I think you will need to provide few more example lines of how your txt file looks and use code blocks as I did while editing your question so we can see how the txt file literally looks

Comment: Here are few lines of my text file <1. #2891880 2022-09-28 16:48:11 10.10.50.204 "user100-prtgadmin" 10.10.50.1 8080 POST /public/checklogin.htm username=prtgadmin&password=*** 200 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"> <2. #3578954 2022-09-28 16:59:38 10.10.50.100 "anonymous" 10.10.50.1 8080 GET /public/login.htm "errormsg=Your login has failed. Please try again!" 200 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko">

Comment: -santiago squarzon any help please

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is only looking for sets of digits with dots between them, only ip addresses match that. The following `([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)+).*([0-9]+(:[0-9]+)+).*([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+).".*?"` will output `2022-09-28 16:48:11 10.10.50.204 "user100-useradmin"` which is a start. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks roosevelt i got my desired out put but some lines of my txt files are like this  <#2891880 2022-09-28 16:48:11 10.10.50.204 "user100-prtgadmin" 10.10.50.1 8080 POST /public/checklogin.htm username=prtgadmin&password=*** 200 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"> and the ragex iam applying is not giving desired out put

Comment: -roosevelt honaker please help i will be very thank full to you

Comment: @SajjadMuslim Sorry, I didn't realize there were more quotation marks later. I edited the regex in my answer it should work now with the whole thing.

Comment: well thanks to you @Roosevelt Honaker for your support, your given Ragex helps me alot to achieve my task. finally i got my desired out put from my complete text line by using different Regular Expression which is   < $regex = '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]{1,3})? ([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+) "(?:[^\\"]|\\\\|\\)*"'>. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

This was my text Line

#2891880 2022-09-28 16:48:11 10.10.50.204 "user100-prtgadmin" 10.10.50.1 8080 POST /public/checklogin.htm username=prtgadmin&password=*** 200 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

And i got my desired out put by using this powershell code

````
$output_file = "C:\my\test1.txt"

$regex = '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]{1,3})? ([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+) "(?:[^\\"]|\\\\|\\)*"'

select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file>```
````